# How to detect the type of data to create MySql table from R

Tags: mysql, r

I have a large data with 100+ columns and I want to decide what type of data is which column so I can create a MySQL table according to that data.

Comment: As written ("Is there an R function", "are there some packages"), this is off-topic ("searching for off-site resources").  Can you rewrite your question so that it is focused on "how can I do this" rather than "is there a package/function that will do this" ?  Is your data in a CSV file to begin with it?  How big is it? Consider looking at functions in the tidyverse `readr` package ...

Answer (score 0):

`RMariadb` is the answer : https://rmariadb.r-dbi.org/

With minimal reprex :

```r
library(DBI)
# Connect to my-db as defined in ~/.my.cnf
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), group = "my-db")

dbListTables(con)
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
```

Generally speaking, for connection you can look there : https://db.rstudio.com/databases/